# Como faço para ao clicar no menu, ele role a pagina ate a div conrespondente?

Tags: jquery

Tenho um menu com uma class com nome 'quemSomos' e tenho uma div com id 'quemSomos', quero que ao clicar no menu, ele role ate essa div quemSomos, eu ate tentei fazer isso com html mas ele rola de uma forma muito bruta, queria que fosse de forma suave, alguém pode me ajudar ?

Answer (score 3):

Precisas de saber a posição do elemento com o ID, e depois podes usar o `.animate()` do jQuery para fazer isso.

Um exemplo simples seria assim:

```
$('nav li').click(function() {
    var pos = $('#' + this.dataset.id).position().top;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: pos
    }, 1000);
});
```

#### Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/cqbfnsce/

No exemplo uso `<li data-id="quemSomos">Quem somos</li>`, por isso procuro o elemento com `$('#' + this.dataset.id)` mas se tiveres o ID noutro sitio nesse menu poderás ter de alterar este seletor.